# Precise, linear interpolation between two 3D planes

Tags: math, 3d

I have two planes `P1` and `P2` specified as normal-distance, or 4D vectors.  I also have a parameter `t`. I need to construct a derived plane `P` which is coincident with `P1` for `t = 0`, coincident with `P2` for `t = 1`, and in-between for `t = (0, 1)`. In the end `P` should also be represented as a 4D-vector.

Intuitively `P` should be constructed such that `P1`, `P2` and `P` intersect at the same line, and the angle P1∠P = (P1∠P2)*t*.

Is there an efficient math for this? Can this be solved precisely?

#### Clarification

Linear interpolation of the angle between planes is actually a requirement. In other words the normal N<sub>P</sub> must linearly rotate between N<sub>P1</sub> and N<sub>P2</sub> through the shortest arc.

Comment: The straight-forward way to code these requirements would be: Calculate the intersection line. Then interpolate the rotation about that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice strategy that utilizes the [vector slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) function for the interpolated plane normal and any point on the common line of the two planes.

Start with the definition of each plane, having normal vectors `n_1 = (nx_1,ny_1,nz_1)`,  `n_2 = (nx_2,ny_2,nz_2)` and distance from origin (measured in the direction of the normal) as `d_1` and `d_2`.

The common line of the two planes is along the (non-unit) direction `e = cross(n_1, n_2)`. The point on this line *closest to the origin* is given by the calculation

```
point = (d_2*cross(n_1,e)-d_1*cross(n_2,e))/dot(e,e)
```

<sub>Notation is in pseudo-code with elements from most common languages</sub>

Keep this to the side for now, and focus on interpolating the normals. I you use a [`n = slerp(n_1, n_2, t)`](https://keithmaggio.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/math-magician-lerp-slerp-and-nlerp/) function it will interpolate along the minimum arc and have equal spacings

```
vector slerp(vector n_1, vector n_2, float t)
    // Assume n_1, n_2 are unit vectors
    // Result is always a unit vector
    float g = dot(n_1, n_2)
    float angle = acos(g)
    float f = sin(angle)
    return (sin((1-t)*angle)/f)*n_1 + (sin(t*angle)/f)*n_2
end
```

So now we can define the interpolated plane using the normal `n = slerp(n_1, n_2, t)` and the distance `d = dot(n, point)` from the projection of the common point to along the new normal.

The algorithm below extends the `slerp` function to work with planes also:

```
plane slerp(plane p_1, plane p_2, float t)
    // extract properties from plane
    vector n_1 = p_1.normal, n_2 = p_2.normal
    float d_1 = p_1.distance, d_2 = p_2.distance       
    // interpolate
    vector e = cross(n_1, n_2))
    vector n = slerp(n_1, n_2, t)
    vector r = (d_2*cross(n_1,e)-d_1*cross(n_2,e))/dot(e,e)
    // construct new plane from normal and distance
    return plane(n, dot(r, n))
 end
```

Some helper functions as expected:

```
float dot(vector a, vector b)
    return a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z
end

float hypot(vector a) 
    return sqrt(dot(a,a))
end

vector cross(vector a, vector b) 
    return vector( a.y*b.z-a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x-a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x)
end

vector operator * (float f, vector a)
    return vector(f*a.x, f*a.y, f*a.z)
end

vector operator + (vector a, vector b)
    return vector(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y, a.z+b.z)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting your solution. I was hoping for something more magical like "convert your planes to quaternions and bingo" but a pure trigonometric solution will have to do. Your code seems very concise.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the formula for *point*? I do realize that *point* is a point of intersection of the two original planes and another plane perpendicular to both and passing through the coordinate system origin. However I do not understand how this equation is derived. Any references?

Comment: The point formula is a combination of two formulas. a) Line that intersects two planes and b) Point on line closest to origin."Foundations of Game Engine Development", Volume 1 - Math, Chapter 3 Plucker Coordinates, Page 129, Equations **E** and **G**. (https://foundationsofgameenginedev.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about efficient in terms of computing time, but it can definitely be solved.

[image]

(Imagine a `P_t` (your `P`) just beside `c_t`. `a`, `a_t`, `b`, and `c_t` are angles.)

In the terms of this illustration, you want `a_t = a * t, t in (0, 1)`.

We want to find `l_t` in terms of `t`, and importantly `l_t` is not simply `t * ||P_3||`.

Firstly, `cos(a) = P1 * P2 / (||P1|| * ||P2||)`, where `*` is the standard vector dot product if between vectors and otherwise the standard scalar multiplication.

Then `a = arccos(P1 * P2 / (||P1|| * ||P2||))`.

Also, `b = arccos(P1 * P3 / (||P1|| * ||P3||))`.

Now, `c_t = pi - (a_t + b)`, and we can use the sine relations to find `l_t`.

`l_t = sin(a_t) * ||P1|| / sin(c_t)`.

Finally, `P_t = (l_t / ||P3||) * P2 + ((||P3|| - l) / ||P3||) * P1`, which lies on the line between `P1` and `P2` and lets `a_t` depend linearly on `t`.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around your answer. It seems to me that it's only partial, explaining basic trigonometry of rotating a vector. Building a plane satisfying my criteria requires more math. Please correct me if I'm wrong.